# How to create a recursive manifest directory

Tags: linux, ls

I need to create a manifest of thousands of files and their directory paths recursively.

Here is an example of how i need the manifest to output

```
This_is_an_example/of_how/i_want_to_display/absolute_paths/
examplefiles.md5
examplefiles.txt
examplefile.wav

This_is_an_example/of_how/i_want_to_display/absolute_paths/part_2/
examplefiles.md5
examplefiles.txt
examplefile.wav
```

the command `tree -fai > manifest.txt` gets me close to what i need but it does not create a line break after the absolute path.

secondly i would like to output sequential files in a subdirectory as 1 single line input for example

```
This_is_an_example/of_how/i_want_to_display/absolute_paths/part_3/
test_file_here_0000001.dpx
test_file_here_0000002.dpx
test_file_here_0000003.dpx
test_file_here_0000004.dpx
```

displayed as below instead

```
 This_is_an_example/of_how/i_want_to_display/absolute_paths/part_4/
 test_file_here_[0000000-0000004].dpx
```

Comment: In the second part, the numbers in given pattern, `test_file_here_[0000000-00001234].dpx`, bears no resemblance to the numbers in the filenames shown.

Comment: _ioshifting_, would you please clarify your original post by clicking on [edit] and expanding on the last example? Folks trying to help here use Comments, but we want you to [edit] the original post so all can see the change requested.

Comment: Sorry both, i have now corrected the example given to correctly match what i am looking to achieve

Answer (score 1):

From `man`:

> ```
>   -R, --recursive
>           list subdirectories recursively
> ```

Try,

```
ls -R /path/to/dir
```

more closely,

```
ll -R /path/to/dir | awk '$1!="total"{print $NF}'
```

Comment: the second example with the awk option prints all the files and folder paths how i need them thank you! - i just need to find out how to edit the sequential files into a singular input when printed out

Comment: do you perhaps know the syntax for the awk part of the script to work on centos? i have gawk installed.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -print | perl -pe 'a=$_; chomp $a; -d $a or s:.*/::'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to find directories and then list their contents, why not use `find` for it:

```
find /path/to/dir -type d -exec bash -O dotglob -O nullglob -c '
    for pathname do
        header=0
        for filename in "$pathname"/*; do
            if [ ! -d "$filename" ]; then
                if [ "$header" -eq 0 ]; then
                    printf "%s/\n" "${pathname%/}"
                    header=1
                fi
                printf "%s\n" "${filename##*/}"
            fi
        done
        [ "$header" -eq 1 ] && printf "\n"
    done' bash {} +
```

This finds all directories in or under the given directory path.  It feeds the pathnames of all these directories to a `bash` script.

The `bash` script will iterate over each directory, printing the directory pathname as a header and listing non-directory entries present in that directory.  At the end, if at least one non-directory file was found in the directory, an extra newline is outputted.

Directories that are empty or that only contains directories are not listed.

For a directory structure such as

```
/dir
`-- a
    |-- b
    |   `-- c
    |       |-- .hidden_file
    |       `-- file
    `-- file
```

This would produce the following output:

```
/dir/a/
file

/dir/a/b/c/
.hidden_file
file
```

Comment: This works very well and displays all hidden files - however i did notice that a lot of the files in the subdirectories appeared to duplicate for example test_file.txt would also have a seperate file labelled ._test_file.txt in some instances whole directories were duplicated.

Comment: @ioshifting I don't think that's a sid effect of using my code. Could you check to see if those hidden and seemingly duplicate file are actually there, and what they are?